# Unable to locate printer

Tags: printing

I have 2, completely different, network printers on the LAN, Xubuntu can not wake either of them from hibernation, Windows computers wake them just fine.

What's the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by Network Manager.  Replacing it with WICD completely solved the problem.  Network Manager continues to be a serious problem, I don't understand why WICD is not the default program.